# Guake throws an error on startup

Tags: ubuntu, d-bus, notifications, freedesktop, guake

I'm using Ubuntu-Server 12.04, but I wasn't sure if this was an Ubuntu specific question, so I'm posting it here.

I got myself a graphical user interface by installing `xinit` and `openbox` (using `apt-get install`). I installed `guake` as well (again using `apt-get install`). However, when I try to run `guake` in my terminal emulator (Sakura), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/guake/guake.py", line 1356, in <module>
    if not main():
  File "/usr/lib/guake/guake.py", line 1299, in main
    instance = Guake()
  File "/usr/lib/guake/guake.py", line 649, in __init__
    notification.show()
glib.GError: GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
```

How can I fix this and get `guake` to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=75078) report indicates it's `sudo apt-get install notification-daemon`.

Comment: When I run the command I get `notification-daemon is already the newest version.`

Comment: Actually, on reboot, it seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and run DBus; specifically you want to use `dbus-launch` to run your X11 session.  `apt-get install dbus-x11` should install the daemon components and `dbus-launch`.

Comment: When I run `apt-get install dbus-x11`, it tells me `dbus-x11 is already the newest version`. When I run `apt-get install dbus-launch`, it tells me `E: Unable to locate package dbus-launch`

Comment: Ok, so it's installed already, you just need to use it.  See `man dbus-launch` for how to integrate it into your `openbox` session.

Comment: I think the error message shows that dbus is running properly, but the expected endpoint is missing.

Comment: Argh.  Yes, not sure what I was thinking yesterday.  dbus is there, notification service is missing.